# Adding merge info to Git history

Tags: git, svn, git-merge

In our company we used to use SVN. Developers used to keep every branch to retain the history of commits, because it would have been lost when the branch was deleted, even when it was merged to trunk.

About a year ago, thankfully we switched to Git. Most of the migration went smoothly, but on some of our repos the information that a branch was merged is missing. Not for all branches, however. I think this happened when a SVN merge was not done on the root directory but in a subdirectory, which is very messy IMHO.

No we have a couple of old branches hanging around we can not delete because we don't want to lose the commit history. The actual code is merged, but Git does not know about it. Is there a way to add a some kind of merge info to a commit in git history?

### Example

My SVN repository looked like this:

```
Trunk   ---[1]---------[3]---------[5]
Branch1      \---[2]---/           /
Branch2       \--------------[4]--/
```

But the migrated Git repository looks like this:

```
Master  ---[1]---------[3]---------[5]
Branch1      \---[2]---/
Branch2       \--------------[4]---
```

The merges in the original SVN repository were made in commits 3 and 5. For reasons unknown to me commit 3 is recognized as a merge by Git, while commit 5 is not. I want to know if there is a way to tell Git that commit 5 was a merge commit too.

Comment: you can add tag, https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging check this documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes hopefully you can achieve this with [Tagging](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging)

however after migration you need to make sure that not further commits are there from git.

from the last commit you can follow the commands like

```
git tag -a SVN -m "Migration commit"
git push origin --tags
```

and you can check using the following command,

```
git tag
```

you can also checkout to that commit anytime untill the tag is present.

Comment: Unfortunately I asked for a tag in my original question but this may not be what I wanted. Does creating a tag save the history even when the branch it is on is deleted?

Comment: I have just checked and, it works, I had branch and i provide a tag in that branch at different commit and I deleted the branch still tag exists with its all history, the reason is branch or tag whatever it just a pointer to your commit, branch/tag does not contains history in it self.

Comment: Thank you, this helps cleaning up the unnecessary branches.